# New Magento Installation Shipping Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shipping-methods

I have a fresh Magento 2.2 installation. 
I only want to sell online products, so I disabled the modules Dhl, FedEx, OfflinePayments, AmazonPayment, Ups and so on, because I don't need them.
I only want to be able to pay with credit card and CoinGate module.

I created some products and wanted to test the process of buying some items.

After I added the product to cart I click on `Proceed to checkout` and then the following exception appears:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Config.php on line 68

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Config.php on line 68
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'array_keys() ex...', '/is/htdocs/...', 68, Array)
#1 /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Config.php(68): array_keys(NULL)
#2 /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php(196): Magento\Shipping\Model\Config->getActiveCarriers('1')
#3 /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php(168): Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor->processShippingChildrenComponents(Array)
#4 /is/htdocs/webroot/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor->process(Array)
```

The same error appears in the admin panel when I click on "Taxes" in `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at `<shop>/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Config.php` and found that the referenced error at line 68 is caused by `$carrierCode`, which is empty but it shouldn't be.

Because I haven't installed all carriers, the array was empty.
I reinstalled a carrier (DHL) with

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_Dhl
```

and

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

so that at least one carrier is enabled, even if I don't use it on the shop.

After that the error disappeared and I'm able to proceed the checkout of an order.

Comment: By default Magento requires at least one shipping method to be enabled. You can enable a free shipping method or create a custom method and display your message there. Another option is to make the product type as virtual. If these two options are not feasible on your scenario, then you have to customize the checkout behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**follow below steps:**

```
*Step:1* login your admin panel
*Step:2* goto STORES -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Mehtods
*Step:3* add shipping method here
*Step:4* save config
*Step:5* now clear cache
*Step:6* run your code
```

I hope it help..!!!

Comment: this does not help. error still apears. What do I have to do if I don't want any shipping method?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Admin panel.
Go to `Store => Configuration => General`
Click on the Store Information, tab and provide your store info and address there.
Also set the shipping origin details in shipping method settings.
Now clear the cache and check.

Comment: I already have store info and address set. Checked again, cleared cache. Same error.